# How to change the transparent image background color in chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

How do you change the transparent image background color in chrome? For example if I have a png with a transparent section I want to change that transparent section's color to red instead of white. Or even better a checkerboard like photoshop

Comment: What's the point of doing that?

Comment: You may need to give some more context or an example.  The way I am reading it suggests that you are referring to `pngs` on websites, for which the background is determined by that page's `CSS`, not Chrome as a whole.

Comment: I think he's asking about viewing an IMAGE not a PAGE.  When viewing a transparent image by itself, that's not in a web page, chrome guesses a background color.  http://latex.codecogs.com/png.latex?c=%5csqrt%7ba%5e2%2bb%5e2%7d  Dark gray is not a good background for an image consisting of black and transparent pixels.

Comment: firefox has a nice addon to *remove* the transparent background. https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/transparent-standalone-imag/

Comment: the most amusing thing on SO is getting the comments, asking `What's the point of doing that?`...  eh.. three dots

Answer (score 9):

You can install [Image Transparency](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/image-transparency/ihnkmjaflangdaififmekbjicpafmdek), a Chrome-Addon, to view a bright-Gray-chess-pattern:

[image: transparent example]

[This link](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/image-transparency/ihnkmjaflangdaififmekbjicpafmdek) does not work as of Dez2021, the developer can be found at https://tomekf.pl/

Similar extensions are:

- [Transparent](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/transparent/phkhgilamababakkmpaegfafbefhgfoe) https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/transparent/phkhgilamababakkmpaegfafbefhgfoe
- [Transparent Standalown Images](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/transparent-standalone-im/inmelfailofaofnfdjdkljfchjhogbmh) https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/transparent-standalone-im/inmelfailofaofnfdjdkljfchjhogbmh

Comment: Please do not post the same answer to multiple questions. If the same information really answers both questions, then one question (usually the newer one) should be closed as a duplicate of the other. You can indicate this by [voting to close it as a duplicate](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/close-questions) or, if you don't have enough reputation for that, [raise a flag](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) to indicate that it's a duplicate. Otherwise tailor your answer to this question and don't just paste the same answer in multiple places.

Comment: Does not work if I open the images from my local file system.

Comment: @MartinThoma for local files you might should use gimp[1] or something similar (not a browser) to open.

[1] https://www.gimp.org/downloads/

Comment: I know that I could do it in Eye of Mate (Gimp is a really bad option to just view an image). But I don't want. I could also download an image and open it in an image viewer. But this question is about Chrome.

Comment: @MartinThoma Maybe write an bugreport. I just found https://tomekf.pl/contact

Comment: This URL is no longer valid.

Comment: @JessicaBrown could you try the both extensions above, I still have the extension in my store.

Answer (score 3):

You could also just open up the developer console (hotkey: <kbd>F12</kbd>) and use some JavaScript:

```
document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing something with HTML then this is the way to go:

`<img src="image.png" style="background:red>"`

If you want to use another image as background then you use this CSS property instead:

`background:url(http://image.png)`

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

There is a chrome extension which allow you to change the behavior of chrome when you open an image: [Image to center](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/image-to-center/kcpejamelebpigblebnbabhndaaffjok?hl=en).

In addition to center the image in the browser instead of having it in the top-left corner, you will be able to select a solid background color of your choice or a checkerboard one like on Photoshop.

It's very useful when you are looking for a well aliased picture as there is a lot of png file with some transparency but which render well only on a white background. So you just lose the interest of having transparency and that kind of pictures are still displayed in the google result with alpha filter.

Comment: unfortunately, this fills the *entire* background with checkerboard, even if the image is just very small.

Comment: @Blauhirn how is it a problem for you? Do you have a use case where this behavior can be disruptive in any way?

Comment: the problem is, you cannot see the image dimensions. the background spans over the entire screen. [this](https://octicons.github.com/img/og/arrow-small-left.png) arrow, for example. with the given extension, you cannot see it's got a width of >900 px.
This is complaining on a rather high level, I admit. But so is OP question :p

Comment: @Blauhirn you're right, the possibility to display a border or something would have been a nice addition.
I get that you meant you can't approximate the dimensions however, when an image is opened in its own window, they are defined in the title of the tab: arrow-small-left.png (1200x600). Still I concede it's not a visual indicator of how big the image can be.

Comment: This is good, but it doesn't change the background for images from the local filesystem or data URI.